# google maps overlay drawing on canvas from asynctask onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, maps, android-asynctask, overlay

I have a google maps mapView which has a custom Overlay on it. This overlay grabs the current coordinates the user is looking at and goes out to a website where it gets an image to overlay onto the map. This is a bad practice because the web request can take a couple of seconds and completely locks up the UI thread so I am trying to fix that problem.

I am trying to fix it by having an AsyncTask which will go grab the image and when its ready draw it on the map. I am trying to pass the Canvas to the AsyncTask so that the draw can occur when ready but the draw does not happen and I notice that the canvas size is 0x0 when it goes to draw.

All of the drawing code worked before I tried to put it into the AsyncTask, its just that it was slow.

This is all in my custom Overlay:

```
public class MapOverlaySevereWeather extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
{
    private GeoPoint lastTopLeft = new GeoPoint(0, 0);
    private GeoPoint lastBotRight = new GeoPoint(0, 0);
    private Bitmap mapImage;
    private Canvas thisCanvas;
    private MapView mMapView;

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow)
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

        if( shadow || MapOverlayHandler.isInMotion() )
        { return; }

        mMapView = mapView;
        thisCanvas = canvas;
        Rect curShown = canvas.getClipBounds();
        GeoPoint topLeft = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(0,0);
        GeoPoint bottomRight = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(curShown.right, curShown.bottom);

        if( !topLeft.equals(lastTopLeft) || !bottomRight.equals(lastBotRight) )
        {
            int sizeX = mapView.getWidth();//curShown.right - curShown.left;
            int sizeY = mapView.getHeight();////curShown.bottom - curShown.top;
            float minLat = (float)bottomRight.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6f;
            float minLon = (float)topLeft.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6f;
            float maxLat = (float)topLeft.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6f;
            float maxLon = (float)bottomRight.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6f;
            String fileUrl = "url that gets image based off lat long size";

            new SevereWeatherAsync().execute(new AsyncOverlayData(fileUrl, canvas, curShown));
        }

        lastTopLeft = topLeft;
        lastBotRight = bottomRight;
        return;
    }

    private class SevereWeatherAsync extends AsyncTask<AsyncOverlayData, Void, AsyncOverlayData>
    {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(AsyncOverlayData result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Log.w("Severe","Drawing on " + thisCanvas.getHeight() + " x " + thisCanvas.getWidth());
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAlpha(100);        
            thisCanvas.drawBitmap(mapImage, null, result.getCurRect(), paint);
            mMapView.invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        protected AsyncOverlayData doInBackground(AsyncOverlayData... params)
        {
            Log.w("Severe","getting image");
            URL imageFileURL = null;       
            try
            {
                imageFileURL = new URL(params[0].getURL());
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageFileURL.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.connect();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                mapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            { return null; }        

            return params[0];
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what is happening is that the canvas you have passed to you AsyncTask is not valid by the time the image has been downloaded.

I think a better solution would be to save the bitmap returned from result.getImage() into an instance variable and then redraw the overlay itself.

So you would have something like ..

```
public class MyOverlay extends Overlay {
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private MapView mMapView;

    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        // .. your drawing code
        if(mBitmap == null) {
            // Better download your image!
            new SevereWeatherAsync().execute(new AsyncOverlayData(fileUrl, void, curShown));
        } else {
            //Draw the bitmap!
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, ...);
        }
    } 

    private class SevereWeatherAsync extends AsyncTask<> {
        @Override
        protected AsyncOverlayData doInBackground(AsyncOverlayData... params) {
            //You background work..
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(AsyncOverlayData result) {
            mBitmap = result.getImage();

            //Now we can redraw the overlay!
            mMapView.invalidate();
        }
    }       

}
```

Comment: Thanks DanielGrech. I definitely think the Canvas is invalid but your suggestion didn't seem to solve it. I have edited my code to reflect an updated attempt. You will notice I am now keeping almost everything I was passing via the AsyncOverlayData as a class variable now.

Answer (score 0):

So this is not the way I wanted to go, and I am not sure its the way google maps was designed but I removed the AsyncTask and am now adding and removing the Overlays themselves when the user is interacting with the map.

Basically removing the overlays and setting a timer when they touch the map and everytime thereafter if they touch again and the timer is still counting I reset it. If the timer finally completes then I add the overlays back in...

---

So when you removed the AsyncTask was the code then placed into the Draw or did you have to overide the onPostExecute outside of the draw?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using the "thisCanvas" variable in the `onPostExecute` method of the AsycTask is incorrect. You should not be storing the canvas in a member variable of the Overlay class and using it in other methods/inner classes. The canvas variable is only guaranteed to be valid during the lifetime of the draw method. So after the AsyncTask completes you should store the resulting image in a member variable of the Overlay and then cause the overlay to redraw. The draw code should then just draw the saved image if the location is still the same.